# Angular JS Application Always Hit If Statement Never Goes on Else Statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Service into Angular JS Application. I am creating user login system by providing username and password. But What ever username or password I enter in input filed its always display message username and password is correct . I want if username and password is correct then I want to display message in angular js application otherwise username and password is not correct but I do not know why it is always hitting on if statement and does not matter if i enter wrong username or password.

Here is my Script code .

```
  ///// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";

        }
        $scope.login = function () {
            var User = {
                Username: $scope.Username,
                Password: $scope.Password,
            };
            myService.AuthenticateUser(User).then(function (pl) {

                if (pl.data) {
                    $scope.msg = "Password or username is correct !";//Always hit on this line
                }
                else {
                    $scope.msg = "Password Incorrect !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                }
                }, function (err) {
                $scope.msg = "Password or username is Incorrect !";
                console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
            });
        };



    }]);



app.service("myService", function ($http) {



    this.AuthenticateUser = function (User) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser", JSON.stringify(User));
    }
})
```

Here is my HTML Code ..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{msg}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Username</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="username" data-ng-model="Username" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Password</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" required data-ng-model="Password" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="Login" value="Login" data-ng-click="login()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
```

Here is the out put ..

[image: click here to see the result]

Comment: try if (pl.data != "")

Comment: sorry still hitting if statement

Comment: with empty input fileld its hit else statement –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the then() block, first try to check the value of pl.data using the below code
console.log(pl.data). 
With this, you will get to know what value is returning from the WCF service.
In case the service is returning True always, then in your Angular, it will always execute the if() statement.
Ex.

```
myService.AuthenticateUser(User).then(function (pl) {
console.log(pl.data)
if(pl.data){
    $scope.msg = "Password or username is correct !"
}
else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the response to your http POST request. My bet is that even with incorrect login information you still make a valid http request and therefore get a valid http response with data (pl.data) that might indicate that the login info is incorrect.

You will only hit the else statement if pl.data is null or undefined. Research javascript conditionals and how they work with objects. If the object exists (not null or undefined) it is treated as true.

Comment: the response of the application is always displaying error message ..  $scope.msg = "Password or username is correct !";.. does not matter if i post the wrong username or password

Comment: i added the result of the out put

Comment: If you are getting a success message with server side authentication - where your username and password are validated on the server - and your request is formulated correctly, then your error is probably on your server application and not your Angular app.


And I meant your HTTP response from the network section of your console for your validation POST request.

Comment: Yes the method is Boolean operations returns only true or false.  The server is validating the data and post methos is working as well. But the Problem is that if i enter wrong username or password then i want to display error message into angular js application that uersname or password is incorrect.  That what i am trying to achieve